# Rewrite Rule not working in .htaccess file Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, apache2, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've created a .htaccess file for my site running on my own server, Apache Ubuntu 22.04, where everything works fine except for Rewrite Rule. I definitely have mod_rewrite turned on as when I created a php file with phpinfo(); it appears in the loaded modules. I have also gone into the apache.conf and sites-enabled conf files and turned AllowOverride to All.

the Redirect Rule works completely fine with no issue yet whenever I try to use the Rewrite Rule it never seems to work.

This code works:

```
Redirect /foobar/ https://example.com
```

However this code doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foobar/$ https://example.com/ [R]
```

This is what I have changed in my apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Would anyone know why this could be, as nothing I've tried works and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what directory is the `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? (Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?) By "doesn't work" you mean it's literally not doing anything? No error? Presumably typing some "nonsense" in the `.htaccess` breaks with a 500 error? What is the `DocumentRoot`? I would not expect this to be `/var/www/` (on later versions), more likely to be `/var/www/html` (however, it would be preferable to customise this further in a vHost). If the `.htaccess` file is not in the docroot then the `RewriteRule` will not match.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing `?` in your rule and the lack of an `L` flag beside the `R` may be causing issues. Generally, when redirecting from one directory to another, you would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foobar/?$ https://example.com/ [R,L]
```

However, if you are redirecting to *the same domain*, then it's generally better (but not required) to exclude the domain name. You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foobar/?$ / [R,L]
```

In the event that you want to have the Uri string *after* `foobar/` to be used with the main domain, which is useful if you're changing your Url scheme from something like `/wordpress/2022/10/05/hello-world` to `/2022/10/05/hello-world`, then you can preserve the string like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foobar/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Be careful with the `[R]` in your rewrite rule. If you do not include the HTTP code, Apache will default to `302`, which is a temporary redirect. If the Url structure is going to change permanently (or for more than a year), it would be better to specify a permanent redirect, which is `301`.

---

Notes about the RewriteRule flags:

| Flag | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `R` | Perform a redirect |
| `NC` | Do not pay attention to the case of the Url |
| `L` | Stop processing additional rules |

If you do not have an `L` in the `RewriteRule` definition but have more rules afterwards, then Apache may just keep on going.

Comment: Nope, it didn't seem to work. I've got a feeling I've done something wrong in my apache.conf file but I've no idea what.